# Overlapping crisscross border in CSS

Tags: css

[image]

im trying to set this up as a div block centered in a section, not sure how to make the divs borders look like so. The top right and left corner have the crisscross effect. Was thinking maybe two divs with absolute positioning, then a div wrapping both of them with relative positioning

Comment: show us your code...

Comment: '<div class="team"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b443055501cb3c85a4a740a/5b48070b33b04e6e0446793a_Rectangle%205.png" width="368" class="image-12"><h3 class="heading-8">The Chiropractors</h3><div class="sectiontitle">THE&nbsp;BEST&nbsp;OF&nbsp;THE&nbsp;BEST</div><p class="paragraph-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id eleifend sem. Cras mattis laoreet lorem non fringilla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aorsit.</p></div>'

Comment: my current code doesn't have the cross, im asking if anyone knows how i can do this

Comment: add your code to the question. not in a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element for the second border:

```css
.crisscross {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.crisscross:after {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="crisscross"></div>
```